# INSERT fails with ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with ORACLE SQL Developer and I created a table with an id as PK, another FK, id_columnx and a column1 and inserted data into them. Then I added another 2 columns, column 2 and column 3 and when I try to insert data into these new added columns, I get the error:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL.

I have to mention that I don't have any triggers on the table and i DO have values in the INSERT statement. There seems to be a conflict with the PK id, but I don't understand why.
So here is the code:

```
create table mytable(id INT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar2(30));

insert into mytable values (1, 'Mary');
insert into mytable values (2, 'John');
insert into mytable values (3, 'Bill');

alter table mytable 
add email VARCHAR2(30);
alter table mytable 
add addess VARCHAR2(30);

insert into mytable (email, addess)
values ('mary@gmail.com', 'Street X');
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Error starting at line : 12 in command -
insert into mytable (email, addess)
values ('mary@gmail.com', 'Street X')
Error report -
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ZAMFIRESCUA_49"."MYTABLE"."ID")
```

Comment: Show us a simplified reproducer. (I.e. create table, insert, alter table, insert.)

Comment: Has you table got a not null clause for one of the columns?

Comment: When you say "insert data into these new added columns", is it possible you should instead be updating "these new added columns" based upon the "id as PK" you inserted earlier?

Comment: So I should just use update?

Comment: Should you just update? It depends! Are you trying to add email and address to the EXISTING rows? Then UPDATE. Are you trying to add NEW rows to the existing ones? Then for each new row you MUST provide at least an ID (if not a NAME) in addition to email and address. By only inserting into "mytable" with the specific columns (email, address), you are NOT inserting in the ID column, so it is left as NULL which is not permitted for the PK of a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT` is for inserting new rows, `UPDATE` is for altering data in the current rows.  As mentioned in the comments, it looks like you want to be updating Mary's row with her email/address:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET email = 'mary@gmail.com',
    address = 'Street X'
WHERE ID = 1 --Mary's ID for example, replace with the ID of the row you want to update
```

You could also use a subquery to find the right ID so you don't have to always look it up:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET email = 'mary@gmail.com',
    address = 'Street X'
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Mary')
```

Edit:

I was thinking there were two tables while writing this answer, you could always just use the `name` field as your filter:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET email = 'mary@gmail.com',
    address = 'Street X'
WHERE name = 'Mary'
```

Comment: The WHERE condition written like that makes no sense - why not just `WHERE name = 'Mary'`? What's the difference?

Comment: @mathguy LOL man, I must have been tired and thinking there were two tables.  Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a PK value in your last `INSERT` after the `ALTER` statements. Try this:

```
create table mytable(id INT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar2(30)); 

insert into mytable values (1, 'Mary'); 
insert into mytable values (2, 'John'); 
insert into mytable values (3, 'Bill'); 

alter table mytable add email VARCHAR2(30); 
alter table mytable add addess VARCHAR2(30); 

insert into mytable (id, email, addess) values (4, 'mary@gmail.com', 'Street X');
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm a beginner and I faced this error many times.